# Regex: replace groups of 4 spaces (from new line until a character) with tabs

Tags: regex

There are a lot of questions about replacing spaces with tabs on here, however this is the first I've come across which needs to limit the replaces to spaces that are before any characters.

So I start with `(?:    )` (that's 4 spaces)

Which gives me:

[image]

However I only want to match the spaces before any words! So I need to ignore the space's after `greedy` and `accept`.

So I try the start line operator `^`. Giving me `^(?:    )`

Which only matches 4 spaces directly prefixed with a `^`

[image]

So I add `+` to match many, final regex is `^(?:    )+`, however that gives me:

[image]

which matches all spaces between the start `^` and a character, like I want, however the matches are not in groups of four! The colour block spans the whole line, which is wrong!

I need some Regex pro's to explain to me where I'm going wrong!

---

### EDIT

Should have probably mentioned, I'm not working to any specific regex engine.

I'd rather the solution not use look behinds, but if it has to, it has to.

---

Here's the text for testing:

```
                output.parents('.datatable-expanded').droppable({
                    greedy    : true,
                    accept    : '.ui-draggable',
                    tolerance : 'intersect',
                    hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
                    drop: function(e, ui) {
                        self.handleDrop(ui.helper, $(this).parents('tr').prev())
                    },
                });
```

Comment: Which language/engine do you use? Does it support lookbehinds?

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch instead of posting pictures, it would be better if it's texts.

Comment: I got a close request saying it is "too broad", but how is it too broad? I'm asking for a specific solution to a specific problem. That is not too broad.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I used pictures to help explain myself. If anything, the pictures make it clearer what i am asking for

Comment: picture makes it clear but how i copy your text and test it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj You are completely right. That went right over my head! My bad, I'll edit now. Thank you

Comment: you won't have a possibility without lookbehind with regex. `(?<![\w])( {4})` negative lookbehind to ensure there's no text before is the only solution I see (replacing capture group by \t to achieve your goal) [Demo here](http://regex101.com/r/zI8fC7/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one seems to work.
It matches the beginning of the string, plus one or more group(s) of 4 spaces.

```
/\G {4}/g
```

[Example here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fR3gF7/2)

Comment: Yes, u're right, it only worked for 2 groups like that (btw you forgot the spaces between the parenthesis in your example).
I edited with a new solution.

Comment: Nice one here, didn't though it could be possible without lookbehind. Glad to still learn :)

Comment: This "accepted" solution does not seem to match subsequent lines. To make it do so, you might need to do something like `/(\G|^) {4}/gm`.

Answer (score 3):

This worked in vscode. It halves the number of spaces that start each line.

Find: `^((  )+)\1`

Replace with: `$1`

Answer (score 2):

Match one or more groups of four spaces, anchored to the beginning of the line:

```
/^( {4})+)/
```

There is no need for look-behinds or look-aheads or look-arounds or `\G` positional assertion support, so this regexp will work in any engine.

Replace the match with the right number of tabs (number of spaces divided by four). In JavaScript:

```
line.replace(
    /^( {4})+/gm, 
    function(match) { return '\t'.repeat(match.length/4); } 
)
```

The above uses the new `String.prototype.repeat` method available in FF, latest versions of Chrome, Traceur, or Node with harmony option. If that's not available, here's a quick polyfill:

```
function repeat(str, n) { return new Array(n + 1).join(str); }
```

Comment: This is a great solution for Javascript! However it requires a callback function, and is not pure regex, which is why I didn't select it as the accepted answer! Thanks

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch Thanks for the note. I would be marginally less unhappy if the accepted answer actually worked.

Comment: When I accepted the answer, I edited it to include your suggestion of `/(\G|^) {4}/gm` (which makes it work, as you said) however the edit has not yet taken place (as it must be approved). If you would rather edit your own post to include the correct answer, I'd happily accept your answer.